# What's the major difference between WebSocket and http protocol?

Tags: http, websocket

What are the major difference between between WebSocket and http protocol ? How is WebSocket protocol different than http?

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703627/websockets-protocol-vs-http/14711517#14711517) covers the differences pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets are totally different than http. It only uses http-like communication for initial handshake.