# Cron job alternative titanium mobile

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I am new to IOS, and I am wondering how to run a cron job on the app.

So for example, a way to track:

- when someone has gone offline/online in a chat, and display this in real time to the opposite user.
- a way to constantly track the location of the user whilst they are using the app.

and so on.

I am aware that one can use "background services", but this only seems to work if they are outside of the app, what if I want to track the persons current location whilst they are using the app and update my model accordingly.

How can this be accomplished, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use websockets or polling, but don't know how to implement this in this case because I don't know about titanium mobile.

Maybe this presentation can help you out:
http://www.slideshare.net/etnatraining/ticonf-realitimeappscalanducci

Comment: Is creating a JavaScript script and running the code that calls the data on a timer a good way to do it? (titanium uses javascript)

Comment: That would be polling, so thats ok. But websockets are realtime and are probably more performant

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

**Offline/Online status in a chat**

Use Sockets or WebSockets for the most accurate informations.

**Tracking a location**

This depend on how often do you want to do it. If (For instance every second) then do it using Sockets/WebSockets if you want to track a client every five minutes I would choose just basic POST request using XHR.

Comment: Thanks, a quick question, why use sockets and not a http request object, are they not the same thing?

Comment: also once i get the updated data from the socket, how do i update the view, given its already been set

Comment: Why Sockets/WebSockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703627/websockets-protocol-vs-http. Do you mean just View or TableView? Anyway I think that you should create another question for this...

Comment: View, i.e. where you load up your controller and place elements on the screen.