# socket invoke vs send put/post

Tags: c#, rest, sockets, signalr, .net-6.0

I have socket service on .Net 6.0 with SignalR.

I want to determine the advantages and disadvantages of sending messages from the client to the service.
Should I use Invoke (SignalR) or RESTful put/post requests.

It seems that Invoke will be faster if the connection is already established, but Rest is probably more "light".
Maybe I'm not right)

---

What are the pros and cons of SignalR Invoke?
And what are the pros and cons of Post / Put?
Which is preferable to use when sending messages from client to service?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: What are the pros and cons of SignalR Invoke ?
And what are the pros and cons of Post / Put ?

when sending messages from the client to the service

Comment: Then seems like primary opinion based ...

Comment: I need to select:
1. Should I use post to send messages from the client to the service, and use sockets for updates clients.
2. Should I use only sockets for all traffic exchange.

Comment: Perhaps the following post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732298/signalr-and-webapi-why-use-a-combination-of-the-two